Pine Script - Long or Short Strategy
Only shorts are not working when using the following code.  It works for LONG & SHORT, only LONGs but not for ONLY shorts.  Shorts are disabled when using longs and so on.
Please can someone help.
// === LOGIC === with time filter added
crsOvr = pr1 > 0.01              // go long when condition is met 
crsEql = pr1 <= 0.0              // close positions long or short    
crsUnd = pr1 < -0.01             // go short when condition is met

// === EXECUTION LONG ===
if date() and crsOvr                         // if "within window of time" AND crossover
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)    //     enter long
if date() and crsEql                         // if "within window of time" AND crossunder
    strategy.close("Buy")                   //     close long        

// === EXECUTION SHORT ===
if date() and crsUnd                           // if "within window of time" AND crossover
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)    //     enter short
if date() and crsEql                           // if "within window of time" AND crossunder
    strategy.close("Buy")  


